# How can I make the DFA respect the final states?

Tags: python, state, dfa

I wrote the code of a DFA for a class. It accepts or refuses certain inputs correctly such as  strings x = abbaaa, y = baba, z = abaaabaaab. What i want to solve is, whenever a smaller string inputs the automata (such as a or ab or b) the code prints that the string is accepted which is incorrect.

[The DFA is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN9Rg.png) 
The code is the following:

'''

```
state = 0
flag = False 
string = input("Introduce the string to determine if is accepted or not by the DFA: ")
separated_string= list(string)
print("The string is:", separated_string)


for i in(separated_string):
    if state==0:
        if i=="a":
            print("From q0 to q1")
            state=1
        elif i=="b":
            print("From q0 to q4")
            state=4
    elif state==1:
         if i=="b":
            print("From q1 to q2")
            state=2
         else:
            print("not accepted")
            flag = True
            break;
    elif state==2:
         if i=="a":
            print("From q2 to q2")
            state=2
         else:
            print("From q2 to q3")
            state=3
    elif state==3:
         if i=="a":
            print("From q3 to q3")
            state=3
         else:
            print("Not accepted")
            flag = True
            break;
    elif state==4:
         if i=="a":
            print("From q4 to q4")
            state=4
         else:
            print("From q4 to q5")
            state = 5
    elif state==5:
         if i=="a":
            print("From q5 to q5")
            state=5
         else:
            print("Not accepted")
            flag = True
            break;

if (flag == True):
   pass
else:
   print("ACCEPTED ")
```

'''

Comment: Just wondering you have no else statement for you first node and overall to end it immediatly with a break?

Answer (score 0):

You accept it when the flag is false.

Swap the statements.

```py
if (flag):
   print("ACCEPTED ")
else:
   print("REJECT ")
```